# Как эффективно использовать пересечения множеств в Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, множества

Интересует, как правильно использовать intersection из pandas, чтобы оптимизровать ниже приведенный рабочий код для частотного анализа лотто. Интересует best practices в написании кода, а не само решение конкретной задачи

Требуется найти 8 наиболее часто встречаемых шара в играх, а далее собрать статистику по кол-ву совпадений выбранных шаров в каждой игре.

```
import pandas as pd 
import argparse as ap


def ArgParser():
    parser = ap.ArgumentParser(description='Description of your program')
    parser.add_argument('-d','--draws', help='Test result', required=True)
    args = vars(parser.parse_args())
    return args

def main():

    args = ArgParser()
    draws = pd.read_csv(args['draws'], sep=';',header=0)
    ballsCounts = (draws.iloc[:,1:8].stack().value_counts())[0:8]
    commonBalls = ballsCounts._index.tolist()

    results = {}
    for row in draws.iterrows():
        draw = row[1].values.tolist()[1:8]
        result =  len(list(set(commonBalls) & set(draw)))  
        results[result] = results.get(result,0) + 1

    print(results)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

Результат вывода.

```
{1: 26, 2: 32, 0: 10, 3: 24, 4: 8, 5: 1}
```

Исходные данные:

```
draw_id;ball1;ball2;ball3;ball4;ball5;ball6;ball7
1;9;11;17;29;30;33;36
2;5;6;9;11;15;33;28
3;4;5;10;14;20;30;8
4;4;21;22;25;26;36;6
5;1;11;13;17;24;29;36
6;2;17;22;24;27;30;1
7;4;15;26;28;29;35;34
8;12;22;24;26;31;33;2
9;6;9;16;24;33;34;17
10;3;8;12;19;27;31;1
11;4;5;7;9;14;20;25
12;9;20;32;33;35;36;22
13;16;19;23;25;29;32;12
14;6;10;11;17;33;35;15
15;1;5;16;19;22;28;33
16;3;6;7;8;16;29;12
17;1;3;10;19;24;32;23
18;9;25;27;29;33;35;22
19;7;13;17;18;21;34;6
20;7;14;18;20;27;33;28
21;1;3;5;8;22;23;25
22;4;5;13;19;28;34;11
23;3;24;26;32;35;36;14
24;2;7;18;22;30;32;4
25;5;22;28;30;31;33;3
26;1;4;6;28;31;32;13
27;7;10;15;18;23;30;8
28;6;10;12;16;18;19;4
29;9;12;16;21;23;27;3
30;6;15;18;19;25;29;2
31;4;7;22;28;29;30;15
32;3;7;14;18;33;35;29
33;4;14;21;23;28;29;30
34;2;5;9;21;26;27;20
35;1;3;9;11;13;17;27
36;11;13;15;28;32;35;18
37;3;11;16;21;28;35;15
38;1;2;12;13;14;15;6
39;5;10;13;16;18;21;20
40;1;4;18;23;32;36;7
41;6;9;13;17;18;35;23
42;11;13;19;23;24;27;12
43;2;3;8;14;32;35;25
44;1;5;12;14;21;25;9
45;2;4;15;25;28;31;9
46;19;21;23;26;30;35;2
47;11;16;22;23;24;30;8
48;8;9;11;27;30;35;32
49;1;15;22;26;31;32;25
50;3;5;8;12;16;21;7
51;7;8;13;21;22;32;30
52;1;4;8;14;27;30;12
53;2;16;20;22;27;30;21
54;1;5;16;25;27;36;22
55;4;26;28;30;32;33;6
56;5;10;13;18;24;27;29
57;1;4;5;8;22;25;28
58;3;11;24;27;29;34;17
59;1;2;6;9;14;23;32
60;5;10;12;15;24;33;22
61;5;12;15;23;24;32;18
62;2;5;11;13;25;28;10
63;8;13;18;19;27;31;12
64;7;9;11;23;32;34;22
65;2;4;7;15;27;30;26
66;4;12;15;16;17;19;11
67;6;7;9;12;17;19;27
68;12;17;25;27;32;33;36
69;6;19;20;26;27;35;21
70;6;15;21;32;34;35;1
71;4;7;9;10;14;23;26
72;6;21;26;30;31;32;28
73;3;8;13;22;29;31;12
74;6;8;13;15;27;34;5
75;8;13;24;29;31;33;6
76;6;14;17;23;26;32;21
77;4;9;15;16;23;32;13
78;1;8;13;23;27;33;24
79;1;13;16;26;29;32;6
80;9;12;16;22;24;35;32
81;8;9;18;19;23;28;20
82;1;6;7;20;28;29;32
83;8;17;22;25;26;31;11
84;3;11;18;24;26;29;1
85;10;11;13;21;27;30;6
86;2;13;23;25;30;35;29
87;14;16;17;25;29;30;4
88;7;8;12;22;25;31;16
89;16;23;24;27;32;33;19
90;6;16;18;25;27;28;7
91;13;15;17;19;24;32;6
92;1;12;15;19;27;34;36
93;3;6;7;9;18;33;31
94;6;11;12;14;21;29;23
95;8;11;14;15;29;36;22
96;1;9;14;25;30;32;26
97;4;10;25;31;35;36;17
98;9;16;27;32;35;36;23
99;10;21;28;29;31;34;17
100;1;12;13;24;26;33;22
101;2;4;15;18;19;30;8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[вопрос из комментариев](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/954414/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be/954701?noredirect=1#comment1594909_954701):

> ```
> df.drop('draw_id',1).T.apply(lambda x: set(x) & common)
> ```
>
> Этот кусок кода возвращает массив из list. Мне нужно к этому выражению
>   добавить условие `where (len(list)) > 1`

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=';',header=0, index_col='draw_id')
common = set(commonBalls)
mask = df.T.apply(lambda x: len(set(x) & common)) > 1
res = df[mask]
```

результат:

```
In [85]: res
Out[85]:
         ball1  ball2  ball3  ball4  ball5  ball6  ball7
draw_id
1            9     11     17     29     30     33     36
5            1     11     13     17     24     29     36
6            2     17     22     24     27     30      1
7            4     15     26     28     29     35     34
12           9     20     32     33     35     36     22
13          16     19     23     25     29     32     12
17           1      3     10     19     24     32     23
...        ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...
92           1     12     15     19     27     34     36
94           6     11     12     14     21     29     23
95           8     11     14     15     29     36     22
96           1      9     14     25     30     32     26
98           9     16     27     32     35     36     23
100          1     12     13     24     26     33     22
101          2      4     15     18     19     30      8

[64 rows x 7 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос:

```
In [458]: common = set(commonBalls)

In [460]: df.drop('draw_id',1).T.apply(lambda x: len(set(x) & common)).value_counts()
Out[460]:
2    32
1    26
3    24
0    10
4     8
5     1
dtype: int64
```

или в виде словаря:

```
In [461]: df.drop('draw_id',1).T.apply(lambda x: len(set(x) & common)).value_counts().to_dict()
Out[461]: {2: 32, 1: 26, 3: 24, 0: 10, 4: 8, 5: 1}
```

Comment: Все правильно понял! Великолепный код! Надеюсь, новичкам этот код тоже будет интересен и полезен.