# Как оптимально и правильно подсчитать кол-во вхождений пар элементов первого множества в подмножествах второго множества

Tags: python, python-3.x, оптимизация, pandas, dataframe

На примере задачи требуется оптимизировать код.

По условию задачи с лотторей требуется для комбинаций пар шаров из списка 12 (наиболее часто встречаемых) подсчитать в скольких играх каждая пара участовала, и выбрать 10 наиболее часто встречаемых пар.

Ниже приведен рабочий код подсчета. Требуется сделать его менее громозким, если это возможно за счет использования возможностей pandas или других библиотек python.

Резльтат работы скрипта для каждой категории. {(комбинация шаров): частота, ...}

```
Категория #1
{(23, 32): 10, (1, 32): 9, (6, 13): 9, (6, 32): 9, (12, 27): 8, (9, 32): 8, (8, 22): 8, (9, 23): 8, (8, 30): 7, (1, 13): 7}

Категория #2
{(4, 28): 8, (7, 18): 8, (11, 17): 7, (4, 15): 7, (24, 33): 7, (11, 15): 6, (15, 28): 6, (4, 25): 6, (4, 7): 6, (11, 28): 5}
```

Исходный код

```
import pandas as pd 
import argparse as ap
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations
from prettytable import PrettyTable
from collections import Counter


def ArgParser():
    parser = ap.ArgumentParser(description='Description of your program')
    parser.add_argument('-d','--draws', help='Test result', required=True)
    args = vars(parser.parse_args())
    return args

def main():

    args = ArgParser()
    draws = pd.read_csv(args['draws'], sep=';',header=0).drop('draw_id',1)

    #Собираем статистику по шарам
    bc = (draws.stack().value_counts())
    bc.index.name ='ball'

    #Выделяем первые 12 часто встречаемых шаров в категорию #1
    bc1 = bc[0:12]
    bc1.index.name ='ball'
    bl1 = bc1.sort_index().index.tolist()
    bl1s = set(bl1)

    #Выделяем следующие 12 часто встречаемых шаров в категорию №2
    bc2 = bc[12:24]
    bc2.index.name ='ball'
    bl2 = bc2.sort_index().index.tolist()
    bl2s = set(bl2)

    print(bc1)
    print(bc2)

    #Собираем статистику с группировкой по кол-во совпадений шаров из #1 категории в каждой игре
    bc1s = draws.T.apply(lambda x: len(set(x) & bl1s)).value_counts().sort_index()
    bc1s.index.name ='count'

    #Собираем статистику с группировкой по кол-во совпадений шаров из #2 категории в каждой игре
    bc2s = draws.T.apply(lambda x: len(set(x) & bl2s)).value_counts().sort_index()
    bc2s.index.name ='count'

    print(bc1s)
    print(bc2s)

    #Генерация комбинаций пар шаров (сочетания) категории #1
    cc1 = list(combinations(bl1,2))

    #Генерация комбинаций пар шаров (сочетания) категории #2
    cc2 = list(combinations(bl2,2))

    sc1 = {}
    sc2 = {} 

    #Подсчет сколько раз каждая сгенерированная кобинация пара шаров встречались во всех играх. Статистика для категории #1 и категории #2  
    for draw in draws.values:
        for c in cc1:
            if(c[0] in draw and c[1] in draw):
                sc1[c] = sc1.get(c, 0) + 1


        for c in cc2:
            if(c[0] in draw and c[1] in draw):
                    sc2[c] = sc2.get(c, 0) + 1


    sc1 = dict(Counter(sc1).most_common(10))
    sc2 = dict(Counter(sc2).most_common(10))

    for key,val in sc1.items():
        sc1pt.add_row([key, val])

    for key,val in sc2.items():
        sc2pt.add_row([key, val])

    print(sc1)
    print(sc2)

    print('The End')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

Исходные данные

```
draw_id;ball1;ball2;ball3;ball4;ball5;ball6;ball7
1;9;11;17;29;30;33;36
2;5;6;9;11;15;33;28
3;4;5;10;14;20;30;8
4;4;21;22;25;26;36;6
5;1;11;13;17;24;29;36
6;2;17;22;24;27;30;1
7;4;15;26;28;29;35;34
8;12;22;24;26;31;33;2
9;6;9;16;24;33;34;17
10;3;8;12;19;27;31;1
11;4;5;7;9;14;20;25
12;9;20;32;33;35;36;22
13;16;19;23;25;29;32;12
14;6;10;11;17;33;35;15
15;1;5;16;19;22;28;33
16;3;6;7;8;16;29;12
17;1;3;10;19;24;32;23
18;9;25;27;29;33;35;22
19;7;13;17;18;21;34;6
20;7;14;18;20;27;33;28
21;1;3;5;8;22;23;25
22;4;5;13;19;28;34;11
23;3;24;26;32;35;36;14
24;2;7;18;22;30;32;4
25;5;22;28;30;31;33;3
26;1;4;6;28;31;32;13
27;7;10;15;18;23;30;8
28;6;10;12;16;18;19;4
29;9;12;16;21;23;27;3
30;6;15;18;19;25;29;2
31;4;7;22;28;29;30;15
32;3;7;14;18;33;35;29
33;4;14;21;23;28;29;30
34;2;5;9;21;26;27;20
35;1;3;9;11;13;17;27
36;11;13;15;28;32;35;18
37;3;11;16;21;28;35;15
38;1;2;12;13;14;15;6
39;5;10;13;16;18;21;20
40;1;4;18;23;32;36;7
41;6;9;13;17;18;35;23
42;11;13;19;23;24;27;12
43;2;3;8;14;32;35;25
44;1;5;12;14;21;25;9
45;2;4;15;25;28;31;9
46;19;21;23;26;30;35;2
47;11;16;22;23;24;30;8
48;8;9;11;27;30;35;32
49;1;15;22;26;31;32;25
50;3;5;8;12;16;21;7
51;7;8;13;21;22;32;30
52;1;4;8;14;27;30;12
53;2;16;20;22;27;30;21
54;1;5;16;25;27;36;22
55;4;26;28;30;32;33;6
56;5;10;13;18;24;27;29
57;1;4;5;8;22;25;28
58;3;11;24;27;29;34;17
59;1;2;6;9;14;23;32
60;5;10;12;15;24;33;22
61;5;12;15;23;24;32;18
62;2;5;11;13;25;28;10
63;8;13;18;19;27;31;12
64;7;9;11;23;32;34;22
65;2;4;7;15;27;30;26
66;4;12;15;16;17;19;11
67;6;7;9;12;17;19;27
68;12;17;25;27;32;33;36
69;6;19;20;26;27;35;21
70;6;15;21;32;34;35;1
71;4;7;9;10;14;23;26
72;6;21;26;30;31;32;28
73;3;8;13;22;29;31;12
74;6;8;13;15;27;34;5
75;8;13;24;29;31;33;6
76;6;14;17;23;26;32;21
77;4;9;15;16;23;32;13
78;1;8;13;23;27;33;24
79;1;13;16;26;29;32;6
80;9;12;16;22;24;35;32
81;8;9;18;19;23;28;20
82;1;6;7;20;28;29;32
83;8;17;22;25;26;31;11
84;3;11;18;24;26;29;1
85;10;11;13;21;27;30;6
86;2;13;23;25;30;35;29
87;14;16;17;25;29;30;4
88;7;8;12;22;25;31;16
89;16;23;24;27;32;33;19
90;6;16;18;25;27;28;7
91;13;15;17;19;24;32;6
92;1;12;15;19;27;34;36
93;3;6;7;9;18;33;31
94;6;11;12;14;21;29;23
95;8;11;14;15;29;36;22
96;1;9;14;25;30;32;26
97;4;10;25;31;35;36;17
98;9;16;27;32;35;36;23
99;10;21;28;29;31;34;17
100;1;12;13;24;26;33;22
101;2;4;15;18;19;30;8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
from itertools import combinations

def pair_freq(a, sort=True, sort_axis=-1):
    """
    calculate frequncy of pairs of all numbers 
    in rows in a 2D array
    """
    a = np.asarray(a)
    if sort:
        a = np.sort(a, axis=sort_axis)
    res = Counter()
    for row in a:
        res.update(combinations(row, 2))
    return res


# read CSV to DF
fn = r'D:\work\.data\SO\954414.csv'
draws = pd.read_csv(fn, sep=';',header=0, index_col='draw_id')

# most frequent balls    
bc = (draws.stack().value_counts())
# top 12 most frequent balls: 1-12
b1 = bc.iloc[:12].index
# second top 12 most frequent balls: 13-24
b2 = bc.iloc[12:24].index

# generate multi-index Series with frequencies for all pairs
r = pd.Series(pair_freq(draws))
# category 1
cat1 = r[r.index.get_level_values(0).isin(b1) & r.index.get_level_values(1).isin(b1)].nlargest(10).to_dict()
# category 2
cat2 = r[r.index.get_level_values(0).isin(b2) & r.index.get_level_values(1).isin(b2)].nlargest(10).to_dict()
```

результат:

```
In [17]: cat1
Out[17]:
{(23, 32): 10,
 (1, 32): 9,
 (6, 13): 9,
 (6, 32): 9,
 (12, 27): 8,
 (9, 32): 8,
 (8, 22): 8,
 (9, 23): 8,
 (8, 30): 7,
 (1, 13): 7}

In [18]: cat2
Out[18]:
{(4, 28): 8,
 (7, 18): 8,
 (11, 17): 7,
 (4, 15): 7,
 (24, 33): 7,
 (11, 15): 6,
 (15, 28): 6,
 (4, 25): 6,
 (4, 7): 6,
 (11, 28): 5}
```

Comment: Надо привыкнуть по новому кодить и максимально эффективно использовать python. @MaxU +1

Comment: @YuriyTigiev, возможно вам будет интересно - [я задал соответствующий вопрос в англоязычном SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55088656/5741205) - на данный момент я получил один ответ, который прибл. в 32 раза быстрее моего... ;)

Comment: Посмотрел, но там и кода побольше и он менее читабельный. У меня назревает свой вариант.

Comment: По этой задаче хочу свое решение предложить, но не могу пока сообразить как вот эту запись записать правильно test = data.T.apply(lambda x: set(x) & bl1s)  я хочу отфильтровать результат apply оставив только множества длина котороых больше 1. Черз фильтр как обратиться к результату?

Comment: @YuriyTigiev, `data[data.T.apply(lambda x: len(set(x) & bl1s) > 1)]` ?

Comment: не за компом. он возвращает list или len(list)? мне нужно чтобы возвращался list где len(list) > 1

Comment: @YuriyTigiev, можете открыть новый вопрос с небольшим примером входных и выходных данных?

Comment: Не за домашним компом. Из твоего примера  "Как эффективно использовать пересечения множеств в Pandas"   `df.drop('draw_id',1).T.apply(lambda x: len(set(x) & common)).value_counts()` - оставь только `df.drop('draw_id',1).T.apply(lambda x: set(x) & common).`  Этот кусок кода возвращает массив из list.  Мне нужно к этому выражению добавить условие where (len(list)) > 1

Comment: @YuriyTigiev, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/955441/211923

Comment: Частично реализовал, то что задумал, но столкнулся с другой проблемой. Чтобы не спамить форум, могу напрямую связаться с вами?

Comment: Не знаю как на  step2 и step3 избавиться от nested list в переменной x.  
   `#выбираем игры у которых при пересечение с bc1 совпадает более 1 шара
 mask = draws.T.apply(lambda x: len(set(x) & set(common.index[0:6]))) > 1
 step1 = draws[mask].T.apply(lambda x: set(x) & set(bc1)).to_frame()
 #формируем комбинации по двум шарам из предыдущей выборки
 step2 = step1.apply(lambda x: list(combinations(x,2))).to_frame()
 #собираем статистику по кол-ву пар. 
 step3 = (step2.apply(lambda x: reduce(operator.concat, x))[0]).values_count()`

Comment: я хотел сделать аналог того, что сделал ты, но при этом без использования функции pair_freq

Comment: поможешь с проблемой из предыдущего коммента?

Comment: @YuriyTigiev, а чем вас не устраивает использование функции?

Comment: Устраивает, однако в процессе обучения и на реальных задачах  я хочу понять какие еще возможности есть у python и pandas.